# Geting maximum prime factor for a given number

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to solve a problem from Project Euler:
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
and here is my attempt:

```
def getPrimeNumbers(testNumber):
    '''
      For a given number it returns a list of all prime numbers from 2 to given number.

      >>> getPrimeNumbers(15)
          [2,3,5,7,11,13]
    '''
    primeNumbers = [2]
    temp=0
    for i in range(3,testNumber):
        for eachElement in primeNumbers:
            if i%eachElement==0:
                break
            else:
                temp+=1
        if temp == len(primeNumbers):
            primeNumbers.append(i)
        temp=0
    return primeNumbers


def getMaxPrimeFactor(testNumber):
    '''
        For a given testNumber it returns a maximum prime factor of that number. Else it returns that number is already a prime!

        >>> (1) getMaxPrimeFactor(15)
                5
            (2) getMaxPrimeFactor(13)
                A number is already a prime!

    '''
    helpList = []
    for eachElement in getPrimeNumbers(testNumber):
        if testNumber%eachElement == 0:
            helpList.append(eachElement)

    if len(helpList) == 0:
        print("A number is already a prime!")
    else:
        print(max(helpList), helpList)
```

For smaller numbers it works, but it takes too much time to solve for 600851475143!

- Can you suggest other solutions, and explain them?
- Given my code, what would you suggest to improve in future?
- Why doesn't return work in `getMaxPrimeFactor()` function, but instead I had to use `print(max(helpList), helpList)`?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI "Can you suggest other solutions, and explain them?" is a code request, asking for code is off-topic here as it's a slippery slope. Some members of the site may provide an alternate solution, with code. But that's out of the kindness of their hearts, not because it's something we should actively be doing.

Comment: Additionally "Why doesn't return work in getMaxPrimeFactor() function, but instead I had to use print(max(helpList), helpList)?" is off-topic as you're asking why your code works. This normally is a sign of users not writing the posted code. Additionally posts asking how code work aren't really that helpful except to you. As part of the Stack Exchange network, we aim to help possible future visitors too. Take people that have completed this Project Euler and search for alternate solutions to see what they could do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I'd suggest printing out the current time three times: at the beginning, after calling `getPrimeNumbers`, and after calling `getMaxPrimeFactor`, to see which function is taking up so much time.
But in this case *both* functions are very inefficient.

Put more effort into designing and analyzing your algorithms, *before* you try coding them in any specific language.

## getPrimeNumbers():

To generate a list of prime numbers, it isn't necessary to test every individual value in the range.
[Sieve of Eratosthenes - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) describes a much more efficient method.

And you can make the range much shorter by realizing that if it the given number itself isn't prime, the next largest candidate will be its square root.
E.g. if the number is 1,000,000, its largest prime factor can't be larger than 1000.
If the number is 600851475143, no prime factor other than itself can be larger than 800,000.

## getMaxPrimeFactor:

Building a list of prime factors, printing the maximum value in the list, then discarding them all is a waste of effort.

Instead of a list, simply keep track of the last prime factor found.

Comment: While this is a good answer, I can't vote it up because the question itself is off-topic. When you see comments that indicate the question is off-topic it is best not to answer it.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, I saw your original comment, but it mentioned "code request" as the reason, so I didn't provide any code.  I treated it instead as a question about what is wrong with the algorithm.  Is critiquing algorithms off-topic here?  Is there a better site for it?

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm a bit confused... So, let's say that the given number is 10. sqrt(10) is around 3,162. That means that all prime factors of 10 lie between [2, 3,162], which implies numbers 2 and 3 since they are prime and thus possible prime factors of 10. Since, 10mod3 is not equal to 0, that means that we discard 3 but are left with 2. 10mod2 equals 0. Since we are left with number 2 only, that means that largest prime factor for 10 is 2, which is not true since 2*5=10 and 5 is also a prime factor. Right?

Comment: @Krushe, yes, I totally blew it.  I was thinking of the test-for-prime algorithm.  Thanks for pointing it out.   FYI, [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-largest-prime-factor-number/) contains some optimization speedups to the algorithm.